# My Twilio Function Is Not Working In Getting Quotes Inside JSON REST API

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I just want to grab some specific quotes in this link https://quotes.rest/qod.json and it's not working.
I copy the code from this tutorial https://youtu.be/wohjl01HZuY and it's not working on my end. The quote i want to get from the json link is not working with the function below.    Can anyone help me? :)

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs('https://quotes.rest/qod.json').then(response =>{
        const qotd = JSON.parse(response.body);
        let quote = qotd.contents.quotes[0];
        callback(null,quote);
    });
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "*it's not working*" is not a problem description. Please edit your question and add details.  What happened?  Did you see errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As user3761325 points out, `fs` is the Node.js file system module and does not make HTTP requests. There are a number of libraries that make it easy to make HTTP requests in Node.js, I personally like [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

When this video was created, the `got` module was actually available by default in Twilio Functions, but that is no longer the case. You need to install `got` into the function dependencies. You can check out [the documentation for adding dependencies to your Twilio Function here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/packages).

Once you have added `got` to your dependencies you can then require `got` and use it to make the request as in the video:

```js
const got = require("got");

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    got('https://quotes.rest/qod.json').then(response =>{
        const qotd = JSON.parse(response.body);
        let quote = qotd.contents.quotes[0];
        callback(null, quote);
    });
};
```

You could do the same with [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: Thank you Philnash. It's working now,
the got dependencies is the reason why it's not running. after I install it the code performs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me , But as much as I know, The **FS** module
represent filesystem module.

Try this code out, This is how you should send HTTP request .

```
let handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  fetch('https://quotes.rest/qod.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const gotd = data;
      console.log(gotd);
      //Your codes Goes Here
    });
}
handler()
```

Comment: The fetch code is not recognized in Twilio function. It returns an error.

Comment: fetch is available in JavaScript, not Node. If you want to use it in node, you need to require the `node-fetch` package as a requirement (and include it in the dependencies for your Twilio Functions - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).